# Delphi route audio to specific channel

Tags: delphi

I wonder if audio can be routed to a specific channel (left or right only)

I've this code, but of course, in this case audio is routed to both channels.

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//                               system
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
constructor TCustomSoundInOut.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);

  SetBufCount(DEFAULTBUFCOUNT);

  FDeviceID := WAVE_MAPPER;

  //init WaveFmt
  with WaveFmt do
    begin
    wf.wFormatTag := WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;
    wf.nChannels := 1;             //mono
    wf.nBlockAlign := 2;           //SizeOf(SmallInt) * nChannels;
    wBitsPerSample := 16;          //SizeOf(SmallInt) * 8;
    end;

  //fill nSamplesPerSec, nAvgBytesPerSec in WaveFmt
  SamplesPerSec := 48000;
end;


destructor TCustomSoundInOut.Destroy;
begin
  Enabled := false;
  inherited;
end;


procedure TCustomSoundInOut.Err(Txt: string);
begin
  raise ESoundError.Create(Txt);
end;
```

Comment: You are creating mono audio, which would normally play on both channels.  You did not show how you are actually playing the audio, but I suspect you are not taking control of the playback channels and pushing audio to only one channel, you are probably just letting Windows play the audio normally.  Please show your actual playback code.

Comment: Hi Remy, The full code is available at https://github.com/VE3NEA/MorseRunner

Comment: I asume the playback code is in the SndOut class as follows:

Comment: procedure TAlSoundOut.Start;
 var
   i: integer;
 begin
   //open device
   rc := waveOutOpen(@DeviceHandle, DeviceID, @WaveFmt, GetThreadID, 0, CALLBACK_THREAD);
   CheckErr;

   //send all buffers to the player
   if Assigned(FOnBufAvailable) then
  for i:=0 to High(Buffers) do
    FOnBufAvailable(Self);
 end;

Comment: Please don't put code snippets in comments. Edit your original question and put the *relevant* code in there, where it belongs. Please don't ask people to dig through your entire project trying to hunt things down. Provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: In any case, it is unlikely that `waveOutOpen()` and related APIs are going to help you much here. You would have to create stereo audio and only populate one channel of it with audio samples. You should consider switching to DirectX instead.  Its DirectSound API provides much more control over playback, including being able to play audio on specific channels.

Comment: you use ancient 16-bit WaveOut API

dunno, but perhaps better to try some more modern APIs like DirectSound or maybe BASS DLL ? 

Sound panning via DirectX: http://delphiworld.narod.ru/base/games_tdxsound.html  (use translate.ru if want to any comments there as well)

Comment: Sound panning with BASS - check "speaker assignment flags" in BASS_CreateStreamXXXX functions - http://www.un4seen.com/doc/#bass/BASS_StreamCreateFile.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Windows Vista or later

You should use `IAudioEndpointVolume` interface from the Core Audio SDK, and more specifically the `IAudioEndpointVolume.SetChannelVolumeLevel()` method:

```
function SetChannelVolumeLevel(nChannel: uint; fLevelDB: double; pguidEventContext: PGUID): HRESULT; stdcall;
```

See documentation here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/dd368053%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

### Before Vista

If you use the "old" MMSystem API, the answer is also given in MSDN doc:

```
MMRESULT waveOutSetVolume(
  HWAVEOUT hwo, 
  DWORD dwVolume 
);
```

> *Parameters*
>
> *hwo*
>
> Handle to an open waveform-audio output device. This parameter can also be a device identifier.
>
> *dwVolume*
>
> Specifies a new volume setting. The low-order word contains the **left-channel volume setting**, and the high-order word contains
>   the **right-channel setting**. A value of 0xFFFF represents full
>   volume, and a value of 0x0000 is silence.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa908146.aspx